How to efficiently remove values below threshold in a stack data structure?
I am trying to implement a stack that supports the following operations:

push: Pushes an integer value onto the top of the stack.
pop: Removes the top element from the stack.
remove_lower value: Removes all elements in the stack that are less than value.
remove_upper value: Removes all elements in the stack that are greater than value.

I need to ensure that all operations are efficient, especially given the potential size of the stack.
I considered using a TreeMap<Integer, Integer> to manage the elements in sorted order and store their counts, but I am struggling with efficiently handling the stack's "last-in-first-out" (LIFO) behavior in combination with threshold removals.
Issues:

Synchronization of TreeMap and stack: The TreeMap efficiently tracks the elements for threshold-based removal, but it does not directly update the stack structure.
Efficiency: Removing elements from both the TreeMap and stack while maintaining acceptable time complexity is proving to be challenging.

Questions:

How can I efficiently synchronize the TreeMap and the stack during remove_lower and remove_upper operations?
Is there a better data structure or approach for handling this problem efficiently, considering both the stack behavior (push/pop) and the threshold-based removal requirements?


A stack supports top, empty, push and pop. No less, and importantly, no more. If you have a different set of supported operations, you don't have a stack any more, but a different data structure.

Consider wrapping your own int[]. Using a primitive array will make searches much faster due to CPU cache locality, compared to a generic collection class where there is no locality. Operations will be O(n) instead of O(log n) but could still be much faster due to said cache locality. It would also be much more space-efficient.

What is the potential size of the stack? How often are things pushed or popped? How often are remove_upper and remove_lower operations performed?

When you are using a stack that literally can only perform the operations push and pop, you’d need a second stack during the “remove lower” operation, to temporarily store the popped values you don’t want to remove. However, that would be just an academic exercise.
For a real world problem, you’d use, e.g. ArrayDeque. It supports push and pop, but you can also call, e.g. stack.removeIf(element -> element < threshold);, on it.
This will work fairly efficient already. There is little you can gain from maintaining an additional data structure, like the TreeMap. The only thing it could tell you, would be whether there is no element below the threshold so you could skip the removeIf in that case. But at the cost of having to update the map on every push and pop while not gaining anything if there are elements to remove. Those additional costs would outweigh the gains in most scenarios.

Thanks for the response. I was using the .removeIf() but I was wondering if there was a way to do it in O(log(n)) while also keeping efficient time complexity for insertion and removal.

It’s possible to have O(log(n)) removal, but in real life, the array based operations are far more efficient than, e.g. using a TreeMap. You’d need a very large number of elements to benefit from the better time complexity, maybe more than the collections can store.

You can create your own stack as two directional linked list.
Use TreeMap to store references to linked list node.

push: add node to beginning of list, update map
pop: remove node from beginning of map, remove node from map
remove_lower: get list of values from map. Remove them from list (it will take O(n) where n is number of removed elements). Remove elements from tree.
remove_upper: same

So

push, pop: O(log(n)) where n is size of collection
remove_lower, remove_upper: O(max(log(n), m)) where n is size of collection and m is number of removed elements.


In O(max(log(n), m) you've got unbalanced parentheses. Did you mean O(max(log(n), m))? That wouldn't make sense, because max(log(n), m) can be made to be equal to either log(n) or m as you please, depending on your chosen log base.

Can you demonstrate that? What base I need to chose to O(max(log(n), m)) = O(m)?

Let's say n = 10,000, m=10. If you want O(max(log(n), m)) = O(log(n)), choose log base 2 since log2(10000) = 13.29. If you want O(max(log(n), m)) = O(m), choose log base 10 since log10(10000) = 4.

Do you understand what O( ) means? it is lim where arguments go to infinity, So you can't choose n or m.

It work only for specific numbers O(log(n)) with log in any base is the same. log(n, x)/log(n, y)= constant (x, y are bases of corresponding logarithms).

You could do this with a binary search tree (or a skip list) that's been modified to maintain an additional link: the insertion order.
Imagine this node type:
class Node
    int data;
    BST left;  // Right and left children
    BST right; // of binary tree node
    BST stack; // link to next item in stack

push and pop become O(log n) operations. remove_lower and remove_higher are O(k log n), where k is the number of items removed. You might be able get O(k) for the remove operations with a skip list. And with the binary tree implementation, too, come to think of it.
But as Holger pointed out in his answer, ArrayDeque works great as a stack and RemoveIf gets the job done. It might not be the most efficient asymptotically, but in actual practice with the data sets that we use today, it's fast.
